# OpenCL.clSetKernelArg returns -51

Tags: c++, opencl

I tried to make parallel bfs in openCL but I didn't have enough experience with c++.
So this is probably memory error, but I really don't know how to fix it.
I also can't find what does error value -51 means.
As a result I got "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCFB06A549 (amdocl64.dll) in my project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" in next line.

main

```
    Graph G(AdjacencyList, Directed);
    int startVertex;
    vector<int> distance;
    vector<bool> visited;
    distance = vector<int>(G.numVertices);
    visited = vector<bool>(G.numVertices);
    bool done = false;
    const bool true_value = true;

    int level = 0;

    // Allocation on device
    const int size = G.numVertices * sizeof(int);
    const int adjacencySize = G.adjacencyList.size() * sizeof(int);


    //OpenCL
    cl_int status;
    cl_int ret;

    cl_platform_id platform_id;
    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, NULL);

    cl_device_id device_id;
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);

    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &status);

    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device_id, NULL, &status);
    cl_mem d_adjacencyList = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, adjacencySize, NULL, &status);
    cl_mem d_edgesOffset = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size, NULL, &status);
    cl_mem d_edgesSize = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size, NULL, &status);
    cl_mem d_distance = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size, NULL, &status);
    cl_mem d_done = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(bool), NULL, &status);
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, d_adjacencyList, CL_TRUE, 0, adjacencySize, &G.adjacencyList[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, d_edgesOffset, CL_TRUE, 0, size, &G.edgesOffset[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, d_edgesSize, CL_TRUE, 0, size, &G.edgesSize[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
    
    distance = vector<int>(G.numVertices, INT_MAX);
    distance[start] = 0;
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, d_distance, CL_TRUE, 0, size, distance.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* source_str = NULL;
    size_t source_size;
    FILE* fp;


    fp = fopen("bfs.cl", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        cout << "Failed to load Kernel\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&source_str, (const size_t*)&source_size, &status);
    status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "bfs", &status);
    
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(int), (void*)&G.numVertices);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&d_adjacencyList);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&d_edgesOffset);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&d_edgesOffset);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&d_edgesSize);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&d_distance); //here retirns -51
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 6, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&level); 
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 7, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&d_done);
```

kernel

```
__kernel void bfs(int n, __global int *adjacencyList,__global int *edgesOffset,__global int *edgesSize,__global int *distance, int level,__global bool *done) {
    int tid = get_global_id(0); 
    if (tid < n) {
        if (distance[tid] == level) {
            for (int i = edgesOffset[tid]; i < edgesOffset[tid] + edgesSize[tid]; ++i) {
                int v = adjacencyList[i];
                if (distance[v] == INT_MAX) {
                    *done = false;
                    distance[v] = level + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Parrison welcome to StackOverflow!

All the `OpenCL` error codes are defined in `cl.h`. In the latest (version 3) `cl.h` you will find the error codes defined between lines 194 and 270, where on line 241 you will find:

```
#define CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE -51
```

So the OpenCL ICD reckons that you have passed the wrong variable size for `distance`.

However, I can see many other errors before this one. For example, you need to set the size of the OpenCL buffers based on the sizes of OpenCL variable not native variables, e.g.:

- `cl_int` instead of `int`
- `cl_float` instead of `float`
- and especially `cl_bool` instead of `bool`.

There is no guarantee that an OpenCL `cl_int` is the same size a host `int` and an OpenCL `cl_bool` is defined as an `unsigned int` which is highly unlikely to be the same size as a `bool`!

Ensure that *all* the parameters to your OpenCL kernel are defined correctly and that
you are creating the correct `buffers` and `variables` for them in the `main` program.